# Construct DFA that accept binary string having odd number of 1’s or even number of 0’s

Tags: string, dfa

The question I have been asked is "Design a DFA accepting the set of all strings with an even number of 0’s and an odd number of 1’s on the alphabet {0, 1}."

Is it correct or wrong. please verify if not correct then share your knowledge.

Answer link: https://engrjobschool.com/stackoverflow/DFA.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The above image is DFA for
" DFA accepting the set of all strings with an even number of 0’s **and** an odd number of 1’s on the alphabet {0, 1}."
**Final State = {S0}**

[image]

The above image is DFA for
" DFA accepting the set of all strings with an even number of 0’s **or** an odd number of 1’s on the alphabet {0, 1}."
**Final State = {start ,S0 ,S2}**

I am unable to open your image. Please, verify your answer with above given DFAs.